# How to boot bootable ISO with PXE?

Tags: boot, iso-image, pxe, syslinux

I have `DHCP/TFTP/Syslinux` installed on my computer in the LAN. With it I can boot any images on any other LAN computers, including diskless, for example, `Memtest86+` and it works.

Also I have some bootable ISO files, which I am using while installing various OSes onto virtual machines.

Can I connect both, i.e. boot some arbitrary ISO with PXE?

Comment: Yes. Using memdisk if your .iso fits in RAM. If not, then there are other ways. For example with iPXE.

Answer (score 0):

Having just DHCP/TFTP and SYSLINUX is not enough for being able to PXE boot/install "any" bootable ISO out there.

Take a look at Serva (I'm related to Serva development) starting [here](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) and continuing [here](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html).

You can see there how to automatically PXE install MS Windows OSs and also how to install Linux distros and boot the live versions of them.

You can eventually reproduce what Serva does with your favorite PXE server.

You can also see Microsoft WDS and MDT but they are just focused on MS OSs.